# firewalld not blocking docker container ports

Tags: docker, centos7, firewalld

I want to explicitly open ports on my centos 7 machine, so I've configured firewalld with drop as the default zone and my external zone on my public facing interface. When I run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` and hit the box on port 8000 it fails. But if I add the port to the external zone. It works. All as expected.

However, when I start a docker container on port 8000, and I hit the box externally, I can get to the service. Which is not what I want to happen. I want that to only be accessible if I open port 8000 on zone external.

Even if I bind the docker container to the public address of the box, it still get around the firewall. I can provide more information if needed like route tables and interface configuration, but I don't quite know what's useful. Looking to learn.

The box has two physical interfaces on it, eth0 which has a public ip assigned to it and eth1 which is connected to the private network, and I want to have accessible.

EDIT SOLVED
added `--iptables=false` to the docker options.

Comment: Remember that Docker opens the ports in the firewall unless you explicitly told it not to.

Comment: Thanks, I added the `--iptables=false` option to docker and it stopped overriding things. What concerned me was that when I run `firewall-cmd --zone=external --list-all` the change didn't show up there.

Answer (score 3):

> Remember that Docker opens the ports in the firewall unless you explicitly told it not to. –

Just needed to add `--iptables=false` to the docker options.

Comment: If I add "--iptables=false" it makes all of my containers to not able to access any hosts outside docker0. Do you have to add any forwarding rules to firewalld?

Comment: how did you solve the issue? I'm also stuck at this very problem. After --iptables=false, now docker does not temper explicitly with iptables but now I'm unable to connect to any host of the internet from inside my container. I have tried everything found on the internet but still out of luck