# Docker-ce oppening Firewalld ports on rocky 8

Tags: docker, redhat, firewalld, rocky-linux

Docker-cd, when run with `-p 3010:3010` bypass the firewall and open the container port to the world...
If i disable docker and run a `python -m http.server`, the port is blocked to the outside (as it should, the default rule is drop) but after the docker run, docker opens it.
This prevents me from running a database or a redis with docker, without these services beeing expoded to the world.

I tried: `--iptables=false`, but got: `unknown flag: --iptables`

(as sugestes in a similar question: [firewalld not blocking docker container ports](https://serverfault.com/questions/713748/firewalld-not-blocking-docker-container-ports))

Anyone knows how to prevent docker from oppening holes in my firewall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to expose a containerized service to the world, just bind it to the loopback address:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:3010:3010 ...
```

Now -- regardless of your firewall settings -- this service will only be accessible locally.

Comment: i didnt even know that syntax was valid! Thx!